# hadoop unjar temp dir is not generated in ${hadoop.tmp.dir}

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, unjar

I encountered one issue where hadoop unjar command doesn't really generate temp jar dir in `/mnt/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`.
The context is that I want to get one shell script file from a jar file using `XXX.class.getResourceAsStream("/my_shell.sh")`. If I use `java -cp` command to run this jar it can executed as I expected.
But if I use hadoop jar command to run this jar I can't get what I want.
After debug I found that the `getResource` URL is like this
`url=file:/mnt/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}/hadoop-unjar1355749400200754398/my_shell.sh`
But actually there is no `hadoop-unjar1355749400200754398` dir generated at all in `/mnt/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}/`.
Also there is no any error message printed. I have searched many docs but didn't find any like this issue.

Note: This main in jar doesn't submit any hadoop job and it only try to get a shell file from jar.
hadoop version is 0.20.2-cdh3u3.

Comment: Try getting the jar location from inside your job and may be print it. For that use thie property `mapred.jar` like `System.out.println(conf.get("mapred.jar"));`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. conf.get("mapred.jar") is null and there is no default value for it.http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/JobConfFile